# TSQL query - return value from other row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a query that returns this

```
USER    GROUP   GROUPCODE
U1      G1      abcd
U1      G2 P    vxyz
U2      G1      abcd
U2      G2      lmno
```

The query looks like this

```
select u.user, g.group, g.groupcode
FROM u
INNER JOIN g ON u.user = g.user
```

Where users are in 'P' groups, I want to get the group and groupcode for the matching 'non-P' groups.
So the above would be like this.

```
USER    GROUP   GROUPCODE
U1      G1      abcd
U1      G2      lmno
U2      G1      abcd
U2      G2      lmno
```

I'm using a very limited proprietary system that doesn't support variables or anything that requires full-text indexed columns. Is there a way to do this or am I dreaming?

EDIT: I'm trying to replace GROUP and GROUPCODE for rows conataining 'P' groups.
The query is sort of like an enrollment file. 'P' groups are like a special version of normal groups. But for enrollment, users in P groups should just be put into the normal version.

Getting the GROUP can be done with this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (RIGHT(SU.FULLNAME, 2) = ' P') 
THEN (substring(g.group, 1, (len(g.group) - 2))) 
ELSE g.group
END AS GROUP
```

But then I cant't figure out how to get the matching GROUPCODE

Comment: Unless you provide more info on how the data is arranged (for instance, is "P" part of the GROUP's string or is a different record in the table?), there is no way anyone can help you.

Comment: More explaination is require. and from your question i get confused.. whether in first table "P" is join with G2 ???

Comment: Yes, P is part of the GROUP string. Thanks.

Comment: Are there cases that more than one 'non-P' group? For instance: more than one group G2. ???

Comment: No, all entries in g.group are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that `GROUP` is always like `'AllText' P`.

```
SELECT
  u.user, 
  CASE WHEN g.group LIKE '%P' THEN LEFT(g.group, 2) 
       ELSE g.group AS group, 
  CASE WHEN g.group LIKE '%P' THEN  (
                                         SELECT TOP 1 gro.groupcode 
                                         FROM g AS gro 
                                         WHERE gro.group = LEFT(g.group , 2)
                                     ) 
       ELSE g.groupcode END AS groupcode, 
FROM 
    u INNER JOIN 
    g ON u.user = g.user
```

Comment: Yes that is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.user, g.group, g.groupcode
FROM u
INNER JOIN g ON u.user = g.user
where r.group no like '%P%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this just excludes rows that have P in the GROUP string.

What i'm trying to do is replace GROUP and GROUPCODE for rows with P groups.